# How to tell if Azure Function App will be restarted?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I plan to update the CORS setting in the Function App.

[image]

How do I know if this change will trigger the Function App to restart?

Comment: @JohnH that is my question. How do I tell if the restart happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**will updating the CORS setting restart the function app host**" quite a simple question one would think it should be somewhere in the documentation; but I cant find any documentation around this and was curious my self so tested it out, I took a running function and enabled CORS and observed in app-insights that it does indeed restart the host, there we go; **yes it does restart**.

[image]