# How to know Azure Function is restarted?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have noticed of my Azure Queue has triggered and after 8 minutes the same queue has started again with the same queue message as per my app insight logs.

Where I can find the Azure logs for queue triggered or function have restarted or function has failed? I have read one of those articles [Azure dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2) where they have explains dependencies.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured Diagnostic Settings for your function then you can query the Log analytics workspace ( usign Kusto query) for FunctionAppLogs like below. The field "Message" contains the reason why the fucntion was executed. For e.g if the function was executed via an API call then you would see something like "Reason=This function was programmatically called via the host APIs". You can search for specific words in the message. Also there is a Level field ( like Information, Warning,Error) on which you can filter. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) is the relevant docs from Azure.

```
FunctionAppLogs
| where Message contains "ServiceBus"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will configure my diagnostic setting and check about functions. One more link I found here regarding my question [Azure Function restarted StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446743/how-to-tell-if-azure-function-app-will-be-restarted)